# Change Page's Function

Tags: javascript, html, function

Im trying to bypass a confirm window that pops up by changing the function that controls it.

It's supposed to return true, which would auto-confirm.

The function is 'confirmTrade()'

```
iframe.contentWindow.confirmTrade() = function(){return true;};
```

Thats what I have, but the script stops there.

Comment: Have you loaded up Firebug (for Firefox), or one of the other development consoles for other browsers? If so, what does it say?

Comment: I can try it in firefox, but ive been working in Chrome

Comment: Then you can use the Chrome development console. Is this on a Windows box? If so, get to it by pressing F12.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the correct object reference for the function…

You need to assign the new function to that property — not *call* the original function and try to assign something to the return value — get rid of the `()`.

```
iframe.contentWindow.confirmTrade = function(){return true;};
```

It would be simpler to just edit the original document, rather than trying to dynamically change it with JavaScript. If the reason you taking this approach is because you don't control that document, then it seems likely that [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will apply.